# How to download a JSON by API call in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, api, url, urllib

I need to download a json file from API using python.

I am having a url like https://API_Key:Password@LINK.com/fileName.json

And I am having Shared Secret code also. I can't download a file without shared secret code. If I try it throws 403 error code. Can anyone help me how to pass the Shared Secret code with the URL to download a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to permission issue. Just check with system admin.